# betterway to retrieve recent 10 items from database in django

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-queryset

I use the query below for retrieving 10 items from my database

```
    itemobjects = Items.objects.all()[:10]
```

Is there a better way to do this? Because when number of items in my database increases the above query is very slow and takes around 1-2 seconds

Answer (score 4):

This shouldn't take long at all, even on large tables. Did you define a default ordering on the `Meta` class of the model? Perhaps it orders on a non-indexed field per default, which would be a reason for the slowdown you're seeing.

Anyway, to get the most recent entries, order them by the primary key (which is guaranteed to be indexed):

```
itemobjects = Items.objects.all().order_by('-pk')[:10]
```

/edit: just a tip: it is a convention to give model classes singular names, e.g. `Item` instead of `Items`.

Comment: try to set an index on that field and see if it helps